# Errors while trying to implement in app purchase to remove ads

Tags: ios7, delegates

I have followed Jojodmo's guide on how to do this but came up with two errors. I've played around with the codes a lot but I'm not quite sure on how to fix these errors. Any suggestions? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare in the interface of your view controller that it is conform to those protocols.

```
@interface ELViewController <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>
```